# Prompt in select tag rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, select, tags, html-select

I have a partial file in my app by rails. In this partial I have select tag, which uses options_from_collection_for_select. So, I want set prompt for this. Any ideas?

```
<%= select_tag :city, options_from_collection_for_select(City.all, 'id', 'name') %>
```

Comment: use :prompt argument with the select tag `select_tag :city, options, :prompt => 'pick a city'` http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html

Answer (score 0):

You can pass `prompt` argument to `select_tag`.

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-select_tag